# Temporal discrete data with ground truth labels for clustering purpose

Tags: data-request, nlp, time-series

I would like to know if there is any temporal discrete data-set available with the ground truth labels. The goal is to test the performance of the temporal/evolutionary clustering methods, such as the Dynamic Topic Model.

Comment: See the answer to [this post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15881/7031).